# how can i run AVD it automatically?

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, sdk

I started to learn React Native but I have an error.

When I use cd ./project folder and use yarn start(I use EXPO)

Console gives me 3 options and I need to click "a" for Android but when I click a I got an error.(Device not found) but If I open project on Android Studio and I select AVD device manager in manually it is works. How can I run in a console without android studio? I want to use phpstorm or visual studio code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Open the terminal
2. Locate emulator folders, if you're using Windows then it should be located at `C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator`.
3. Run this `.\emulator -list-avds`. you will get your emulator name that you've installed. copy the name of your emulator.
4. Finally, run this `.\emulator -avd $emulator_name`(REMOVE `$emulator_name` with your emulator name.

with these steps, it should able you to open emulator without open Android Studio.